# mysql count votes optimization

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

so im making a file hub nothing huge or fancy just to store some files that may be shared by others for download. and it just occured to me in the way that i originally intended to count the amount of upvotes or downvotes the query could be server heavy.the query to get the files is something along the lines of

```
select*from files;
```

and in such i would recieve an array of my files that i could loop over and get specifics on each file now with the inclusion of voting a file that same foreach loop would include a further query that would get the count the amount votes a file would get (the file id in the where clause) like so

```
select*from votes where upvoted=true and file.id=?
```

and i was thinking of using pdo::rowCount to get my answer. now evey bone in my body just says this is bad very bad as imagine im getting 10,000 files i just ran 10,000 extra queries one on each file and i havent looked at the downvotes yet which i was think could go in a similar fasion. any optimization adviece here is a small rep of the structure of a few tables. the upvoted and downvoted columbs are of type bool or tinyint if you will

```
   table: file                table: user                table: votes       
+----+-------------+    +----+-------------+ +--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id |storedname   |    | id | username    | |file_id | user_id| upvoted | downvoted
+----+-------------+    +----+-------------+ +--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| 1  | 45tfvb.txt  |    | 1  | matthew     | | 1      |  2     |    1   |      0
| 2  |jj7fnfddf.pdf|    | 2  | mark        | | 2      |  1     |    1   |      1
| .. | ..          |    | .. | ..          | | ..     |  ..    |    ..  |      ..
```

Comment: why would you have a for loop do the extra queries like that? why not just do a select with your file data and join the votes table to it? then do a for loop afterwards to loop through.

also doing select * from is a bad habit.. if there is more specific stuff you want then specify that... it will make things run a LOT faster

Comment: @JohnRuddell that select* is not my actual query am just trying to simplify. and i dont have that file.id part untill i do run my query

Comment: here is the actual get all files query if it helps                         SELECT `logical_name` , `file_type` , `physical_name` , `uploader_notes` , `views` , `downloads` , `user`.`name` , `category`.`name` AS `category_name`
FROM document
INNER JOIN category ON document.category_id = category.id
INNER JOIN user ON document.uploader_id = user.id
ORDER BY category.id                                                          minus any refrences to the votes table but the votes table is as i have illustrated.

Comment: ok but you are pulling out a list of files (that have id's in the table) right? I guess what I mean is why not just do SELECT * FROM votes WHERE fileID IN(SELECT ID FROM FILE)... different variations on that.. but you should be able to get everything you want from one select for votes table and then match with a for loop to your file select.. instead of doing thousands of selects in a for loop

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes a sub query seems to be what i want let me check up on how i can incoperate that into my current query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways to do this. the better way to do this (aka faster) is to write separate queries and build into one variable in your programming language (like php, python.. etc.)

```
SELECT 
    d.id as doc_id,
    COUNT(v.document_id) as num_upvotes
FROM votes v
JOIN document d on d.id = v.document_id
WHERE v.upvoted IS TRUE
GROUP BY doc_id
);
```

that will return your list of upvoted documents. you can do the same for your downvotes.

then after your select from document do a for loop to compare the votes with the document by ID and build into a dictionary or list.

---

The second way to do this which can take a lot longer at runtime if you have a bunch of records in the table (its less efficient, but easier to write) is to add subquery selects in your select statement like this...

```
SELECT 
    logical_name ,
    document.id , 
    file_type , 
    physical_name , 
    uploader_notes , 
    views , 
    downloads , 
    user.name , 
    category.name AS category_name,
    (Select count(1) from votes where upvoted=true and document_id=document.id )as upvoted,
    (select count(1) from votes where upvoted=false and document_id=document.id) as downvoted 
FROM document 
INNER JOIN category ON document.category_id = category.id 
INNER JOIN user ON document.uploader_id = user.id 
ORDER BY category.id
```

Comment: hitting the database thousands of times is much slower than doing one query that compares tables thousands of times. :)

Comment: Ruddel see if you can follow my messed up logic what i need is kind of the reverse of that which you stated. i need to select alot of columbs from the files table that inner join with other tables and i also need to get the votes of a specified file id that i get from the previously mentioned or outer query if u will

Comment: ok so you want to pull out multiple columns from your files table... that files table is joined to two other tables right? and then you want a count of upvotes and down votes for the files? is the up and down votes stored in the category table?

Comment: perfect you have it and no the upvotes and downvotes are stored in a seperate table in the exact fasion that i illustrated in the question. i know if they were stored in the categories table i could just use the inner join and all would be nice but they are stored in a seprate table. i did once try to simply try to  add the votes table to the join via a left join but didnt work so well

Comment: so you want your up and down votes to not be joined to the table in the first select?

Comment: i have no problem with them being joined

Comment: here is something that works i think this is called a corellated subquery. SELECT `logical_name` ,`document`.`id` , `file_type` , `physical_name` , `uploader_notes` , `views` , `downloads` , `user`.`name` , `category`.`name` AS `category_name`,(Select count(1) from votes where upvoted=true and document_id=document.id )as upvoted,(select count(1) from votes where upvoted=false and document_id=document.id) as downvoted
FROM document
INNER JOIN category ON document.category_id = category.id
INNER JOIN user ON document.uploader_id = user.id 
ORDER BY category.id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49421/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-alex-zander)

Answer (score 1):

Two advices:

1. Avoid `SELECT *` especially if you're going to count. Replace it, with something like that:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(1) AS total WHERE upvoted=true AND file.id=?
   ```
2. Maybe you want to create a TRIGGER to keep update a counter in the *file* table.

I hope it will be helpfull to you.

Comment: that mention of a trigger also sounds like a plausible solution i shall also research that. is it possible to run a count on a subquery and return it as a columb?

Comment: Excuse me, but I couldn't make a comment yet (I need more reputation to do that). And, yes, you can update your file column in each votes insert or update to keep the calculated field up to date.